# Where is my Plus button (Firefox)?

Tags: firefox

There is a button known as "add a new tab button" or Plus as I call it by its pet name. It just disappeared the other day. It's been missing for days now. I don't know what to do. I am really worried about it. What happened to it? Should I call in the authorities to search for it?

This is a picture of what it looked like the last time I saw it.

[image: missing Plus]

Have you seen this button? Do you know where I can find it?

Yeah, I'm making a joke out of it. But seriously though, the cute little button is really missing, and I would love to recover it, safe and sound. This is Firefox 20.0.1 running on Windows Vista Ultimate SP2. I might even go put up some posters for it in the morning. I liked that little guy.

**Update:**

I tried adding a New Tab button, as suggested by AthomSfere, from the Customize Toolbar window. But it just isn't the same. You can see that from the image below.

[image: customize add new tab button]

The image above looks a little bit different from the first one because it shows the program window in maximized mode. Here's the same window again (in "restored" mode).

[image: customize add new tab button]

And no, I can't move it to the right of the tab. It just doesn't seem to be the same button.

Comment: Backup your profile,, delete it, and see if it will return.

Comment: Instead of printing signs, why not try while logged on as another user? Perhaps try reinstalling FF.  How about a System Restore to  a point before it ran away from you (probably screaming)? :)

Comment: @Ramhound Can you elaborate a little on how to backup the profile, how to delete it, and how to restore the profile?

Comment: This is a wild guess... okay, maybe not so wild... but... I think this may have something to do with the fact that I have many tabs open. I have 118 tabs open right now. My average is 91 tabs. I admit it, I'm a tab junkie! Maybe that's why Plus ran away from me? I was pushing it too hard. I feel guilty...

Comment: Undo your re-add of the button, and then do it again. But when you add it drag it all the way to the far right

Comment: @Sammy - There is documentation on the Firefox website on how to backup a Firefox profile.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! Though I didn't have to delete and mess with my profile. It's enough to just clear the `localstore.rdf` file (see my answer down below).

Comment: @AthomSfere I actually tried what you suggested and the first time I tried it, it didn't work as expected. What happened was that the button looked the same way but it snapped next to the Minimize button in the upper right corner of the window. But I tried this today before I did the procedure as described below, and it did actually work as expected (that is a different style of button and if floats with the tabs as you move them). So this could be a possible solution, but doesn't seem consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found my Plus! :)

Here it is:

[image: Plus is back]

Yeee!.....

The localstore.rdf file stores toolbar and window size/position settings. It can be deleted to resolve various issues, including this one. Here are two ways to resolve this issue.

### Primary method

This method is the easiest and it is the preferred method. But I actually used the second method because I didn't know at the time that I can do it this way. So I recommend this method.

1. Close Firefox.
2. Run `firefox -safe-mode` to start Firefox in safe mode. *(Another way is to hold Shift and click on the Firefox icon on start menu.)*
3. On the Firefox Safe Mode dialog, check the option "Reset toolbars and controls" and un-check everything else.
4. Click "Make Changes and Restart". If Firefox doesn't start within the next two minutes you can start it manually.
5. Done!

### Alternative method

Here's another way to clear this file by deleting and re-creating the profile.

1. Close Firefox.
2. Locate your Firefox profile by running `%appdata%\mozilla\firefox\profiles`. You will see a folder named like `xxxxxxxx.default` or similarly. This is your profile.
3. Copy the profile to e.g. the Desktop.
4. Start Profile Manager by running `firefox -p`.
5. Select the profile ("default" by default) and click Delete Profile button.
6. Select Delete Files.
7. Click Exit.
8. Start Firefox. If prompted, choose not to import any settings or bookmarks.
9. Close Firefox.
10. Run `%appdata%\mozilla\firefox\profiles` and open the new profile folder.
11. Copy everything from your backed up profile folder to the new profile folder, **EXCEPT** the files `localstore.rdf` and `localstore-safe.rdf`. *If prompted, choose to replace any existing files and folders.*
12. Start Firefox.
13. Done!

Answer (score 4):

If you go to

Tools -> toolbars -> Customize

You should see "New Tab", just drag and drop that where you want it.

If that fails, click the restore to default option.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. That's like his ugly cousin. It just isn't the same. And it's accessed by right click on the navigation toolbar, and then Customize. From the Tools menu you can only access the Options dialog. See the update above.

Comment: This is the best tip so far so I'll give it an up-vote.

Comment: :) in my case, it magically appeared after I opened Tools -> toolbars -> Customize and then closed it

Answer (score 0):

Following what in the support page of mozilla <sup>[[1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076124)],[[2](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars)]</sup> from Firefox version 39 it should be visible by default on the sidebar.

It can be removed by customization and restored in different ways via `option menu`-->`customize` panel on the right of the bar or clicking with the right button of the mouse when over the bar and selecting customize:

- If you find it <sup>[[1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076124)]</sup>  you can move adding in the original position

  [image]

  It can be even in the right panel of the available icons.

  - As last attempt you can use the *Restore to default* button after that you access the customize panel.